# How to use wget to grab copy of Google Code site documents?

Tags: html, wget, curl, google-code

I have a Google Code project which has a lot of wiki'ed documentation. I would like to create a copy of this documentation for offline browsing. I would like to use `wget` or a similar utility.

I have tried the following:

```
$ wget --no-parent \
       --recursive \
       --page-requisites \
       --html-extension \
       --base="http://code.google.com/p/myProject/" \
       "http://code.google.com/p/myProject/"
```

The problem is that links from within the mirrored copy have links like:

```
file:///p/myProject/documentName
```

This renaming of links in this way causes 404 (not found) errors, since the links point to nowhere valid on the filesystem.

What options should I use instead with `wget`, so that I can make a local copy of the site's documentation and other pages?

Comment: Just FYI, the source for the wiki pages is located in your source repository. So you could download them all and run them through your own renderer.

Comment: That doesn't help me because it contains a lot of Google Code markup. I'm asking how I would do this with `wget` or `curl` (or similar), I think.

Comment: @AlexReynolds this will help to that https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-code-wiki-viewer/

Answer (score 2):

If the URL looks like:

```
https://code.google.com/p/projectName/downloads/detail?name=yourFILE.tar.gz
```

Turn it into:

```
$wget https://projectName.googlecode.com/files/yourFILE.tar.gz
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of playing around, I managed to get the following to work for me:

```
$ wget --no-parent \
       --recursive \
       --page-requisites \
       --html-extension \
       --convert-links \ 
       -E -l 3 \
       http://code.google.com/p/myProject/
```

The result is entirely self-contained, now.